# Concatenate specific files into one single file

Tags: files, cat

In a folder containing X files, I need to concatenate Y files (where X > Y) together into a single text file. I have the filenames (of Y files) that I need to concatenate.

Comment: In what format do you have the Y files?

Comment: @forcefsck: They are in text format as well

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `cat` command (see `man cat` for more information) to concatenate the text files.

If you want to create a new file

```
cat [FILE1] [FILE2]... > new_file
```

or if you want to append to an existing file use it like this

```
cat [FILE1] [FILE2]... >> file
```

Comment: This, however, does not show how to read the filenames from a list and apply `cat` to them.

Answer (score 8):

If the Y filenames are listed in a `list` file, a simple combination of `xargs` and `cat` is enough:

```
xargs cat <list >>concatenation_of_files
```

In the case you've been careful and you've listed files one per line (to avoid problems with spaces in filenames), then just add a `-d` delimiter option:

```
xargs -d'\n' cat <list >>concatenation_of_files
```

(This assumes `concatenation_of_files` is initially inexistent or empty).

Comment: Cool! Obvious but didn't see it.

Comment: You may use `>outputfile` to truncate the output file.  This is ok as it's the output from `xargs` that is redirected, not from the individual `cat` invocations.

Answer (score 4):

Answers are using bash.

Let's say you want to concat json files in your directory:

```
cat *json > all.json
```

Including subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar
cat **/*json > all.json
```

However, if you have thousands to millions of files, you will encounter:

```
bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

In which case, do the following which also outputs the current file being processed:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm concat.json
find . -path "**/*.json" | while read -r file; do
    echo -ne "\\r$file"
    cat "$file" >> concat.json
done
```

Posted on this question, as [this other question became closed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/113715/50703).

Comment: This does not read the filenames from a list.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer but, yes, this isn't answering the question. Also, you can just do `for f in **/*.json; do cat "$f" >> concat.json` or `find . -path "**/*.json" -exec cat {} >>  concat.json` .

Comment: Problem is the question that this answers was marked as a duplicate of this question, which it is not exactly. Seems this question is then intended to become the one for accomplish its aims in the most broadest of sense.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this is REALLY late and not actually an answer but a suggestion if you are doing this.)

Do not use the same file extension as the files that you are concatenating.

```
cat *.json > all.json.txt
```

Then come back and...

```
mv all.json.txt all.json
```

Not actually sure if this solves the problem in the question but this will avoid the looping issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately, it is not clear which "looping issue" is being avoided; please consider adding more explanation.