# How can I concatenate all files in a directory together in one command line operation?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, xargs, cat

I have 1000 csv files in a directory. I would like to concatenate them all together in order. They are named img_size_1.csv to approx img_size_1000.csv
[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31863/concatenate-specific-files-into-one-single-file) is close but assumes a list file. Can this be done in a one-liner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a dupe of the linked question. This is exactly the same issue, the OP just did not know how to use globbing/wildcards.

Comment: With `zsh`: `< *.csv(n) > all.csv` (`n` for numeric sort)

Answer (score 31):

Yes it can, with the unimaginatively named `cat` command:

```
$ cat *csv > all.csv
```

`cat` does what it says on the bottle, it conCATenates its input and prints to standard output. The command above will give an error if a file called `all.csv` already exists in the target directory:

```
$ cat *csv > all.csv
cat: all.csv: input file is output file
```

<del>You can safely ignore that error, the contents of `all.csv` will be overwritten.</del>  Apparently, on some systems (e.g. OSX according to the comments below this answer), you cannot ignore the error and this will enter a loop, catting `all.csv` back into itself until you run out of disk space. If so, just delete `all.csv`, if it exists, before running the command.

Comment: If the command is carried out more that once (so all.csv will exist), one may not wish to concatenate all.csv with the other .csv files. rm all.csv first?

Comment: @terdon, thanks. Is there any way to affect the order in which the files are added to be sure that they will be processed in numeric order? Or by date?

Comment: @suspectus no, that is not needed. The `> all.csv` will truncate `all.csv` (empty it) _before_ anything else is run (shell comands are run right-to-left). Therefore, `all.csv` will always be empty and you will not get the repetition you are thinking of.

Comment: @codecowboy by default, the glob (the `*csv`) is expanded in alphanumeric order so it should do that already. If not, please [edit] your question to explain exactly what your file names look like. Do you have both `file_N.csv` and `fileN.csv`?

Comment: @terdon thanks for the illuminating explanation.

Comment: interestingly on OS X bash 3.2 the destination file is not overwritten first. If all.csv exists then do `cat *.csv > all.csv` the operation does not return and continues to add to all.csv until out of disk space.

Comment: Thank you @suspectus for pointing this out.  I've also encountered this on other platforms.  It is definitely not "safe" to ignore "input file is output file".  It may not have caused problem for the poster, but it invites a race condition and could fill up your hard drive if you are away making coffee.  NOT SAFE!

Comment: @Owen fair enough. I've never seen this behavior, so thanks to you and suspectus for letting me know. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ran this `cat ./**/*json > all.json` and got this error `bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long` guess it doesn't like running on millions of files. Any suggestions?

Comment: Figured it out: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/437084/50703

Answer (score 7):

```
ls -1 *.csv | while read fn ; do cat "$fn" >> output.csv.file; done
```

If you want to concatenate them by alphabetic order :

```
ls -1 *.csv | sort | while read fn ; do cat "$fn" >> output.csv.file; done
```

If you want to concatenate them by time creation order :

```
ls -1t *.csv | while read fn ; do cat "$fn" >> output.csv.file; done
```

Comment: I fixed the quoting and format issues but this will break on files whose names contain newlines or backslashes and it will re-concatenate everything into the output file every time it is run, so you should make sure that `output.csv` does not exist before running it. Oh, and the `sort` in undeeded, `ls` with no options will already sort files alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks ! The `sort` just prevent any `ls` aliasing.